# Apoll server prop 'body' does not exist on type 'IncomingMessage'

Tags: node.js, typescript, server, apollo

I am working on an apollo node server in typescript. After migrating to Apollo V4 every req.body i call returns the error " property 'body' does not exist on type 'IncomingMessage'"

small snippet of example code

```
context: async ({ req }) => {
    let storedContent = {
      uid: "",
      originalAccess: "",
      originalRefresh: "",
      NewAccess: "",
      NewRefresh: "",
    };
    try {
      //Catch uid from playgorund headers and log path
      if (req.headers.uid) req.body["uid"] = req.headers.uid;

      console.log("UID", req.body.uid);
```

Comment: Please add more code.

Comment: It seems the apollo startStandaloneServer should include body parsing but is doesnt work for some reason